# Doctrine 2 Relations Mistake

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with inserting record into my DB.
I have 3 tables named
notifications:
id, id_event, event_id, is_readed
comments:
id, comment, receiver, sender, created_at
messages
id, subject, message, receiver, sender, created_at

I want to relate comments and messages id for notifications.id_event with many-to-many relation, which looks like

```
oneToOne:
    comment:
        targetEntity: Comments
        joinColumn:
            name: id_event
            referencedColumnName: id

    message:
        targetEntity: Messages
        joinColumn:
            name: id_event
            referencedColumnName: id
```

When I'm trying to insert a record I have the following exception:

> Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on
>   association Privatmarket\BusinessBundle\Entity\Notifications#message,
>   but expecting Privatmarket\BusinessBundle\Entity\Messages

And realy don't understand what to do. Maybe I make the mistake in relation choosing ?

The insert code is:

```
        $comment = new Comments();
        $comment->setSender(rand(1, 10));
        $comment->setReceiver(rand(11, 20));
        $comment->setComment("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet {$i}, olor sit amet {$i}, psum dolor sit amet {$i}, olor sit amet {$i}, ");
        $em->persist($comment);
        $em->flush();

        $notification = new Notifications();
        $id = $comment->getId();
        $notification->setComment($em->getRepository("PrivatmarketBusinessBundle:Comments")->find($id));
        $notification->setEventId(2);
        $em->persist($notification);
        $em->flush();


        $message = new Messages();
        $message->setSender(rand(1, 10));
        $message->setReceiver(rand(11, 20));
        $message->setSubject("Lorem ipsu{$i}.");
        $message->setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet {$i}, olor sit amet {$i}, psum dolor sit amet {$i}, olor sit amet {$i}, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet {$i}, olor sit amet {$i}, psum dolor sit amet {$i}, olor sit amet {$i}, ");
        $em->persist($message);
        $em->flush();

        $notification = new Notifications();
        $id = $message->getId();
        $notification->setComment($em->getRepository("PrivatmarketBusinessBundle:Messages")->find($id));
        $notification->setEventId(1);
        $em->persist($notification);
        $em->flush();
```

Comment: Could you paste insert code?

Comment: I'm already add code

Comment: I can't see any line of code where you set "Messages" from notification. Are you sure this is code raising that error?

Answer (score 0):

well the error you get reads like change

```
message:
    targetEntity: Messages
    joinColumn:
        name: id_event
        referencedColumnName: id
```

to

```
message:
    targetEntity: Message
    joinColumn:
        name: id_event
        referencedColumnName: id
```

mind that an doctrine expects an entityName as singular so if its a collection it auto-pluralizes getter and setters, maybe this is a bit mixed up

Comment: Wow, this could be a very smart answer without any more details. But no code where "Message" is setted were reported so, before give you the "good answer point" I want to see OP's code :)